# How to parse a single JSON array of objects?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm calling the API endpoint and the JSON response looks like this:

```
    {
        "id": 299536,
        "cast": [
            {
                "cast_id": 1,
                "character": "Tony Stark / Iron Man",
                "credit_id": "54a9cfa29251414d5b00553d",
                "gender": 2,
                "id": 3223,
                "name": "Robert Downey Jr.",
                "order": 0,
                "profile_path": "/1YjdSym1jTG7xjHSI0yGGWEsw5i.jpg"
            },
            {
                "cast_id": 6,
                "character": "Thor Odinson",
                "credit_id": "54a9d012c3a3680c29005762",
                "gender": 2,
                "id": 74568,
                "name": "Chris Hemsworth",
                "order": 1,
                "profile_path": "/lrhth7yK9p3vy6p7AabDUM1THKl.jpg"
            },
            {
                "cast_id": 13,
                "character": "Bruce Banner / Hulk",
                "credit_id": "573fc00592514177ec00010a",
                "gender": 2,
                "id": 103,
                "name": "Mark Ruffalo",
                "order": 2,
                "profile_path": "/isQ747u0MU8U9gdsNlPngjABclH.jpg"
            }
           ]
```

This is the struct that I've made for the codable protocol.

```
struct MovieCast: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let cast: [Cast]
    let crew: [Crew]
}

struct Cast: Codable {
    let castID: Int
    let character, creditID: String
    let gender, id: Int
    let name: String
    let order: Int
    let profilePath: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case castID = "cast_id"
        case character
        case creditID = "credit_id"
        case gender, id, name, order
        case profilePath = "profile_path"
    }
}

struct Crew: Codable {
    let creditID: String
    let department: Department
    let gender, id: Int
    let job, name: String
    let profilePath: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case creditID = "credit_id"
        case department, gender, id, job, name
        case profilePath = "profile_path"
    }
}

enum Department: String, Codable {
    case art = "Art"
    case camera = "Camera"
    case costumeMakeUp = "Costume & Make-Up"
    case crew = "Crew"
    case directing = "Directing"
    case editing = "Editing"
    case lighting = "Lighting"
    case production = "Production"
    case sound = "Sound"
    case visualEffects = "Visual Effects"
    case writing = "Writing"
}
```

My question is, how can I loop through the objects in a single array using Swift 4? I am using Decodable protocol and have struct that looks like this: (note that I let out some of the json response properties above so the snippet wouldn't be too long)

My goal is to get the

> profile_path

out of every object and append it to the array of Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your MovieCast struct contains 2 arrays, one of `Cast` objects and one of `Crew` objects.

You could create a protocol `Staff` that has the shared properties from both (`gender`, `name`, `profilePath`), declare that both types conform to that protocol, and then combine your arrays of `Cast` and `Crew` objects into an array of `Staff`.

Then you could map the resulting array to an array of strings from the `profilePath` values of each entry in the array:

```
protocol Staff {
  var gender: Int { get }
  var name: String { get }
  var profilePath: String? { get }
}
```

Change Cast and Crew like this:

```
struct Cast: Codable & Staff

struct Crew: Codable & Staff
```

if you have a crew:

```
var movieCrew: MovieCast
//Code to load a moview crew
```

Then

```
let castAndCrew = (movieCrew.cast as [Staff]) + ((movieCrew.crew as [Staff]?) ?? [])
let allProfilePaths = castAndCrew.compactMap { $0.profilePath }
```

(Note that I typed this into the SO editor, and my syntax is rarely perfect "out of the gate." It will likely need some minor cleanup.)

Comment: True. I shouldn't post code like that because newbies will actually try and **do** that. (In the code I used to tinker with this the var was an optional that would only be nil if a try block failed, and that would catch the error case.)

Answer (score 0):

After you get the response try this code in `viewDidLoad()`

```
if let dict = response.result.value as? [string:Anyobject]() //fetching the response
if let innerdict = dict["cast"] as? [[string:Anyobject]]() 

for cast in innerdict {
    if let profile_path = cast[ "profile_path"] as? String
    print("profile_path") // to check the profilepath
```

}
    // this is it to get the profile path then append it in the array of type string